# How to prevent Pycharm from opening the source file of a function or a class when trying to edit a particular line,or a function/class name?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

My current Pycharm version is 2023.2.5(Ubuntu linux)
Whenever I try to edit a name of a function or click on a classname it takes me to it's source file which is annoying.How to disable this feature?

```
from .views import test  

"""when I click on the above line to add test2,it takes me to the views.py
Expected behavior:-Should be able to edit a line(add to the end of it) without Pycharm taking me to the source file of that function or class..."""

urlpatterns = [path('home', test, name='test'),
               path('about', test2, name='test2')]
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research I figured out the problem was due to the keymap which I added to open files with single click in new tab.
In Pycharm
`Ctrl Alt S->Keymap->Jump to Source->right click on it->remove click` worked for me!